# major trouble matching selecting most current row

Tags: php, mysql, variables, select

I am having major trouble selecting the most current/matching row in my database.

For example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Password_Reset`";
    $request = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($request);
```

`$result['token']` is taking the first row's no matter what every time the query is run.

I am pretty sure it has to do with not being specific enough with my select query but I have not found a way to match it up.

to be even MORE specific. This is the whole query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Password_Reset`";
    $request = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($request);

    $token = $result['token'];

    $alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    $rand = str_shuffle($alpha);
    $salt = substr($rand,0,40);
    $hashed_password = sha1($salt . $_POST['Password']);
    $user_email = $result['email'];





       // these should match, and do so every where else on my other pages and in the db, I'm just not able to pull the corresponding $token. its taking the $token in the first row every time.
    if($get_token == $token) {
    header("Location: http://www.cysticlife.org/index.php");    
    exit;
    }else{

    if(empty($_POST['Password'])) {
        $valid = false;
        $error_msgs[] = 'Whoops! You must enter a password.';
    }

    if($_POST['Password'] != $_POST['passwordConfirm'] || empty($_POST['Password'])) {
        $valid = false;
        $error_msgs[] = "Your password entries didn't match...was there a typo?";
    }

    if($valid) {
        $query = "UPDATE `cysticUsers` SET `encrypted_password` = '$hashed_password' WHERE `Email` = '$user_email'";

        mysql_query($query,$connection);
    }


    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order your rows by when they were submitted to the database, you will need to add an ID-Field to your table, if you haven't got one already.

It will probably be the easiest way to add an field called `id` to the table, set it as index and use `auto_increment`. Then, you can simply order your rows by ID:

```
SELECT * FROM `Password_Reset` ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Btw, if you only need the first row, it's good to add a `LIMIT 1` to your query, for better performance.

Comment: I do have a auto increment id row indeed. I was quite certain is was related to that. just a newbie and looking for the logical syntax to write it. thanks so much

Comment: if your still interested in helping, that is not solving the problem. It appears to still be selecting the first row. Its not selecting the relevant $token

Comment: Oh, do you want to get the first row that matches a token? Then you would need to use a WHERE-Clause (before the `ORDER BY`), something like `WHERE token = '$token'`.

Comment: ok cool. that makes sense, but its okay that $token is defined AFTER that said query via $result['token']?

Comment: yeah I thought I tried that, because I'm printing $token after the page load, and when I add WHERE token = '$token' it yields $token empty as opposed to having it be the original prolbem...only the first row in the db :/

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM `Password_Reset` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";thank again for your help and keep up the good work ;)

Comment: @andre_roesti -  Just thought I'd let you know that this did it:$query = "SELECT * FROM `Password_Reset` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1"; thanks again and keep up the good work ;)